# How to fix npm start error in my react app?

Tags: reactjs

Getting the following error when I run npm start in my newly created react app that I created using npx create-react-app my-app. I tried uninstalling create react app globally and then updating my node.js version to the latest available but still getting this error. Any advice on how to fix this?
I'm on mac os

Thanks

````
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:614
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for '/Users/quinnbarnett/Desktop/ugh/ugh/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:492:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/quinnbarnett/Desktop/ugh/ugh/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parse.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ugh@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ugh@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. ```
````

Comment: what version u using? It's a node error, and supposingly fixed when you update to min v14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try update to min v14.5 for your node.
2. Try installing autoprefixer@9.8.0 with npm i autoprefixer@9.8.0

It looks like a bug in node.js and there's an issue open for it.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9273

Comment: ``` $ node -v
v13.2.0 ``` Just realized I was still using this version I guess even though I updated to 15.2.1 but having trouble switching to the new version.  I tried ``` brew switch node 15.2.1``` but it wouldn't let me overwrite it.

Comment: Ahh ok did it via nvm after downloading that, thank you!